# Determining the sign of a solution to a Cauchy problem

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose that $y\in C^1(\mathbb{R})$ is the solution of
\begin{cases}
y'(x)=  \sin (y(x)+x^2) \qquad x\in\mathbb{R},\\
y(0)=0.
\end{cases}
I have to prove that $y(x)>0$ if $x\in(0,\sqrt{\pi})$ and that $y(x)<0$ if $x\in (-\sqrt{\pi},0)$.

Here what I have tried:
Since $y\in C^1(\mathbb{R})$, by the chain rule $y'(x)=  \sin (y(x)+x^2)$ is also $C^1$. So, iterating this procedure $y$ is $C^\infty$. Then, differentiating the first equation, you can compute the values of all the derivatives of y in zero:

$y'(0)= \sin (y(0)+0^2)=0, $
$y''(x)= (y'(x)+2x) \cos (y(x)+x^2), \quad y''(0)= (y'(0)+2\cdot0) \cos (y(0)+0^2)=0,$
$y'''(x)= -(y'(x)+2x)^2 \sin (y(x)+x^2) + (y''(x)+2) \cos (y(x)+x^2), \quad y'''(0)=2,$

and so on. So, the Taylor expansion of $y$ near to $x=0$ is $y(x)=x^3+r(x)$, where $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{r(x)}{x^3}=0$. Then, near to $0$, $y$ resembles a cubic, which positive for $x>0$ and negtive $x<0$, but I do not know if this argument can be made rigorous.

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

In a short description of the geometric situation, the function $f(x,y)=\sin(y+x^2)$ has positive values $f(x,0)$ on the $x$-axis for $x^2\in(0,\pi)$. Thus on $(-\sqrt{\pi},\sqrt{\pi})$ it can not be crossed downwards. The only way to have $y(0)=0$ is to have $y<0$ for $x<0$ and $y>0$ for $x>0$ inside this interval.

For your task solution you might have to find more detailed justifications for these steps.